# 16 bit logic/computer simulation in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, computer-science, cpu-architecture, swift-playground

I’m trying to make a basic simulation of a 16 bit computer with Swift. The computer will feature

- An ALU
- 2 registers

That’s all. I have enough knowledge to create these parts visually and understand how they work, but it has become increasingly difficult to make larger components with more inputs while using my current approach.

My current approach has been to wrap each component in a `struct`. This worked early on, but is becoming increasingly difficult to manage multiple inputs while staying true to the principles of computer science.

The primary issue is that the components aren’t updating with the clock signal. I have the output of the component updating when `get` is called on the output variable, `c`. This, however, neglects the idea of a clock signal and will likely cause further problems later on.

It’s also difficult to make getters and setters for each variable without getting errors about mutability. Although I have worked through these errors, they are annoying and slow down the development process.

The last big issue is updating the output. The output doesn’t update when the inputs change; it updates when told to do so. This isn’t accurate to the qualities of real computers and is a fundamental error.

This is an example. It is the ALU I mentioned earlier. It takes two 16 bit inputs and outputs 16 bits. It has two unary ALUs, which can make a 16 bit number zero, negate it, or both. Lastly, it either adds or does a bit wise and comparison based on the `f` flag and inverts the output if the `no` flag is selected.

```
struct ALU {
    //Operations are done in the order listed. For example, if zx and nx are 1, it first makes input 1 zero and then inverts it.
    var x : [Int] //Input 1
    var y : [Int] //Input 2
    var zx : Int //Make input 1 zero
    var zy : Int //Make input 2 zero
    var nx : Int //Invert input 1
    var ny : Int //Invert input 2
    var f : Int //If 0, do a bitwise AND operation. If 1, add the inputs
    var no : Int //Invert the output
    public var c : [Int] { //Output
        get {
            //Numbers first go through unary ALUs. These can negate the input (and output the value), return 0, or return the inverse of 0. They then undergo the operation specified by f, either addition or a bitwise and operation, and are negated if n is 1.
            var ux = UnaryALU(z: zx, n: nx, x: x).c //Unary ALU. See comments for more
            var uy = UnaryALU(z: zy, n: ny, x: y).c 
            var fd = select16(s: f, d1: Add16(a: ux, b: uy).c, d0: and16(a: ux, b: uy).c).c //Adds a 16 bit number or does a bitwise and operation. For more on select16, see the line below.
            var out = select16(s: no, d1: not16(a: fd).c, d0: fd).c //Selects a number. If s is 1, it returns d1. If s is 0, it returns d0. d0 is the value returned by fd, while d1 is the inverse.
            return out
        }
    }
    public init(x:[Int],y:[Int],zx:Int,zy:Int,nx:Int,ny:Int,f:Int,no:Int) {
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.zx = zx
        self.zy = zy
        self.nx = nx
        self.ny = ny
        self.f = f
        self.no = no
    }
}
```

I use `c` for the output variable, store values with multiple bits in `Int` arrays, and store single bits in `Int` values.

I’m doing this on Swift Playgrounds 3.0 with Swift 5.0 on a 6th generation iPad. I’m storing each component or set of components in a separate file in a module, which is why some variables and all `structs` are marked `public`. I would greatly appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: "increasingly difficult to manage multiple variables" Start by giving them clear names. "It is the ALU I mentioned earlier... It has two unary ALUs " Your ALU has two ALUs? what does that mean?

Comment: A unary ALU modifies a single 16 bit input. The ALU utilizes them to perform operations on specific inputs. The unary ALUs aren’t the actual ALU.

Comment: I’ve added some to the question, @Alexander

Comment: Hey Alex, I would really like to help on this question, because it's personally interesting to me. But with how it's written now, I really can't help. All the variable names are cryptic. I'm sure it makes sense in your head, but it won't to others (including yourself, 6 months in the future after you've forgotten what you know now). Could you try refactoring it a bit first, then I can try to take a stab at it?

Comment: @Alexander I added an explanation for the variable names

Comment: It's still incredibly unclear, but just some surface questions: shouldn't `zx`, `zy`, `nx`, `ny` be `Bool`s? So `f` stores your opcode, and there are currently only two (`AND`, `ADD`). What's `UnaryALU`, `select16`, `Add16`, etc.?

Comment: I didn’t use `Bool` because it is more accurate, in my mind at least, to use an `Int` Of 0 or 1. I’ve added some more clarification. I’m sorry, but I just don’t see what is unclear

Comment: "is more accurate" Obviously I take you don't mean this in like a "its stored value differs from the expected value", so in what sense do you think it's less accurate? Is it that you're conceptualizing some register somewhere, and that you would talk about a bit in that register, taking it to be 0 or 1? "I just don’t see what is unclear" That's the thing about convoluted code, it's never usually convoluted to the author (until they forget about the details and come back to it in some number of months)

Comment: It really works either way, I just initially choose `Int`.

Comment: So you just have statement like `if nx == 0 { /* invert */ }` all over the place? ANyway, you didn't answer my questions about `UnaryALU`, `select16` and such. Also, you say "The output doesn’t update when the inputs change; it updates when told to do so." Isn't that a feature not a bug? "Being told when to change" is exactly like a clock pulse on a digital circuit

Comment: I think there's two good approaches to this: 1) you can use a functional reactive framework like RxSwift or Apple's Combine, to expose your ALU's data as observable streams of values. Interconnections between logical components just consist of subscriptions/reactions to these streams of values over time. Alternatively, you can embrace this "stepping" behaviour, emulate a digital clock, and use that to drive your logic. That has the benefit of easily being able to store system states, such as for being able to "rewind" the behaviour of your circuit

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200083/discussion-between-alexh-and-alexander).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I’ve completely redone my approach and have found a way to bypass the issues I was facing. What I’ve done is make what I call “tracker variables” for each input. When `get` is called for each variable, it returns that value of the tracker assigned to it. When `set` is called it calls an `update()` function that updates the output of the circuit. It also updates the value of the tracker. This essentially creates a ‘copy’ of each variable. I did this to prevent any infinite loops.

Trackers are unfortunately necessary here. I’ll demonstrate why

```
var variable : Type {
    get {
        return variable //Calls the getter again, resulting in an infinite loop
    }
    set {
        //Do something
    }
}
```

In order to make a setter, Swift requires a getter to be made as well. In this example, calling `variable` simply calls `get` again, resulting in a never-ending cascade of calls to `get`. Tracker variables are a workaround that use minimal extra code.

Using an update method makes sure the output responds to a change in any input. This also works with a clock signal, due to the architecture of the components themselves. Although it appears to act as the clock, it does not.

For example, in data flip-flops, the clock signal is passed into gates. All a clock signal does is deactivate a component when the signal is off. So, I can implement that within `update()` while remaining faithful to reality.

Here’s an example of a half adder. Note that the tracker variables I mentioned are marked by an underscore in front of their name. It has two inputs, `x` and `y`, which are 1 bit each. It also has two outputs, `high` and `low`, also known as carry and sum. The outputs are also one bit.

```
struct halfAdder {
    private var _x : Bool //Tracker for x
    public var x: Bool { //Input 1
        get {
            return _x //Return the tracker’s value
        }
        set {
            _x = x //Set the tracker to x
            update() //Update the output
        }
    }
    private var _y : Bool //Tracker for y
    public var y: Bool { //Input 2
        get {
            return _y
        }
        set {
            _y = y
            update()
        }
    }
    public var high : Bool //High output, or ‘carry’
    public var low : Bool //Low output, or ‘sum’
    internal mutating func update(){ //Updates the output
        high = x && y //AND gate, sets the high output
        low = (x || y) && !(x && y) //XOR gate, sets the low output
    }
    public init(x:Bool, y:Bool){ //Initializer
        self.high = false //This will change when the variables are set, ensuring a correct output. 
        self.low = false //See above
        self._x = x //Setting trackers and variables
        self._y = y
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    }
}
```

This is a very clean way, save for the trackers, do accomplish this task. It can trivially be expanded to fit any number of bits by using arrays of `Bool` instead of a single value. It respects the clock signal, updates the output when the inputs change, and is very similar to real computers.